# ERROR > java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_LAF_WINDOWS_XP_ENABLED

Tags: java

I m trying to import an existing java project to Netbeans.
I already import related jar files to the project but when I run the main class, it throws this exception.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_LAF_WINDOWS_XP_ENABLED
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:85)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:126)
    at org.addition.epanet.ui.EpanetUI.main(EpanetUI.java:579)
C:\Users\Monster_PC\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: That sounds like a version incompatibility of some sort. Meaning that one of your libraries depends on something ... that looks different in reality. But without a [mcve] not much else to say.

Comment: I think you will have to study http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/looks/ really closely, and maybe you start by checking of the version of jgoodies you are using looks is latest greatest.

Comment: Dear @GhostCat thanks for your response.
I m kind of new with java. I just trying to prepare environment.
I imported "jgoodies-looks-2.4.1.jar". But Im not sure what I need to do now.

Comment: You gave us probably 5% of the information of what you really did. Sorry, that isn't enough. You need to be at least able to communicate that [mcve] to us. And honestly: maybe you are simply overburdening yourself. Instead of trying to use some arbitrary third party library ... why not just go with ordinary, basic java first. You try to get something to work that might cost me some time to get working. Why dont you start with the simple hello world stuff?

Comment: thanks for advice. You're right this is out of my field. 
I am using Epanet water hydraulic simulation software. And I have to make an optimization of a water distribution system.
I am trying to make this optimization steps easier. there will be 50 iteration steps.
and I found "https://baseform.com/" who develope smthng good in java in my field. And they release the library.
I though it will be a good idea to use their example sotfware.
I know basic java. I can develope small stuff like simple address notebook etc.
So that is all my story :)
preparing the environment is very hard for me

Comment: As said, with your current input, we can't help much. We would have to see exactly how your setup looks like to hunt down the bug. Sorry, but unless you can provide that [mcve] your question should be closed as "off topic". You are like a guy calling his vet "my cat is making strange noises. now, tell me how to help her". Sorry, impossible. You need an expert sitting down with you, working through your setup. That is not what this community is for ...